# fragment en android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Hola estoy usando fragment en android y el problema es que desde un boton que tiene una activity llama a un fragment pero las vistas del activity se superponen en el fragment

esta es la activity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando pulso en el floatingbutton llama al fragment pero queda detras de las vistas de esa activity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el metodo onClick del floating button

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Dates fragment = new Dates();
        //secondA es el id del FrameLayout
        transaction.add(R.id.secondA,fragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

este es el metodo onCreateView del fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dates_inputs, container,false); 

    return view;
}
```

layout del activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="practica.myapplication.SecondActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/secondA">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:src="@drawable/add" />


<Button
    android:text="Boton de la activity"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentir"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

layout del fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="practica.myapplication.Dates"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:background="@color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorText"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Datos"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fecha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Fecha"
            android:drawablePadding="7dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendario"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/trabajoR"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/trabajo"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Trabajo realizado"
            android:drawablePadding="7dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cliente"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cliente"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cliente"
            android:drawablePadding="7dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancelar"
            android:background="@color/colorText"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aceptar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Aceptar"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

hay alguna manera de que las vistas del activity queden detras del fragment?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes poner el layout del activity y del fragment

Comment: lo que pasa es que estás reemplazando el contenido dentro de el elemento que está en tu layout : <include layout="@layout/content_second" />  ,   por lo que la parte de atrás aún se superpone

Comment: ese <include layout="@layout.content_second me lo agrego automaticamente android al crear un activity con el tema "basic activity" que viene con un floating button. intentare borrar ese layout y crear el floating button por mi cuenta a ver si se soluciona. gracias por la ayuda

Comment: necesitas si o si ese floating button?

Comment: lo digo porque tienes "boton de actividad" y también el floating button

Comment: @LuchoJuniors como realizas la transaccion del fragment?

Comment: @diegoveloper si, ese boton actividad es nada mas de muestra para que se vea que las view del activity se superponen al fragment

Comment: @LuchoJuniors ya veo, agrega content_second.xml por favor

Comment: @LuchoJuniors espero mi solución te ayude :)

Comment: En este caso no hay varias soluciones, simplemente debe agregar un FrameLayout que no sea el layout principal para realizar la transacción (agregar su Fragment).

Comment: @LuchoJuniors  No se debe cambiar el layout principal del MainActivity, se debe agregar un Framelayout dentro del mismo y dejar los elementos comunes dentro del  Layout que carga el MainActivity.

Comment: Bueno al parecer el problema era bastante tonto. mi falta de experiencia en android hizo que tarde tanto en darme cuenta. El primer error era que el fragment debia estar en un Frame como me marcaron y el segundo error era que el frame de la actividad tenia que estar debajo de todo el codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui el problema es que estas agregando el Fragment dentro de tu Layout principal de la activity:

```
transaction.add(R.id.secondA,fragment);
```

Lo cual es incorrecto, por esa razón los elementos se sobreponen:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/secondA"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="practica.myapplication.SecondActivity">
```

Para solucionar esto, considera agregar un FrameLayout en tu .xml y ahí es donde se reemplazaría el contenido de tu Fragment.

Al agregar el Framelayout indica solo cambia el Id para que realice la transacción del Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Dates fragment = new Dates();

        //* Define id del framelayout.
        transaction.add(R.id.?????,fragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

Comment: Alguna razón por el -1???

Comment: yo no e puesto el -1.  te comento, puse un frame dentro del coordinatorLayout con id: secondA pero sigue pasando. actualizo el codigo

Comment: @LuchoJuniors en el layout del Fragment deben aparecer únicamente elementos que son exclusivos del fragment, por lo tanto tendrías que quitarlos del layout del Activity.

Comment: probe con sacar el boton actividad y poner un checkBox pero me sigue apareciendo arriba del editText del fragment

Answer (score 1):

Ok, el problema es que no se debería usar el [CoordinatorLayout](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37053505) como contenedor de fragmentos, usa `FrameLayout` en su lugar, por lo que el Layout de tu Actividad quedaría así:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/secondA"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="practica.myapplication.SecondActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:src="@drawable/add" />


<Button
    android:text="Boton de la activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Pruébalo y nos cuentas

Comment: e cambiado el Constrainlayout de la actividad por un FrameLayout pero sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: Typo mio, me refiero al layout de tu actividad, cambia el CoordinatorLayout por un Frame, no necesitas el content main, lo que puse yo es el layout de tu activity