# Ir de fragment a otro, a través de un menu item en Android

Tags: java, android

Quiero ir de un framgent a otro a través de un menu item, estuve tratando de hacerlo mediante un intent, pero no lo conseguí, como puedo resolverlo?

[image]

por ejemplo:
haciendo click en el menu item, pasar del fragment "PERFIL" a "CONTACTO"

este es el codigo del menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_first"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_next"
    android:title="Chat"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

este es el codigo del fragment "PERFIl":

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_first, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_first) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Este es el código del fragment "CONTACTO" que es al que quiero pasar:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_second) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Agradeceria mucho de su ayuda.

Comment: para ir de un fragment a otro se usa fragment transaction ó Navigation components https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122069/fragment-en-android, https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started